# Research design: Term for assigning participants to groups depending on day (instead of randomisation)

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, random-allocation

I am looking for the term used to describe when participants are assigned to experiment groups based on the day. We tested several classes in a training centre and selected randomly which class should be tested on which day. However, on a certain day, all participants were assigned to a certain group. The assigned group was switched depending on the day. Thus, randomisation was not conducted on a participant but rather group level.

Is there a professional term I could use to describe the allocation behavior?

Comment: A term that comes to mind is cluster-randomization. Cluster-randomized trials randomly assign clusters of units to the experimental conditions (e.g., treatment and control). Clusters may be most anything, but generally are some naturally occurring group of units.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense!